# Javascript expression in SCSS

Tags: javascript, ruby, compass-sass, sass

I have a @for loop in my SCSS file like:

```
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .cell:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        … //some code here
    }
}
```

Works fine. But I need to calculate some properties using javascript expressions like `Math.sin()` for example to have something like:

```
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .cell:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        top: Math.sin(90) * 150 * -1;
        left: Math.cos(90) * 150;
    }
}
```

Get the error in SCSS compiler. Is there any way to use javascript expressions or it's an abuse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core Sass math is fairly simple, but [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) comes with a load of [helpers](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/), including `sin()` and `cos()` functions. Once you get Compass set up, you can do this:

```
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .cell:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        top: sin(90) * 150 * -1;
        left: cos(90) * 150;
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! Happy coding!